# Discord bot ban and kick commands not working properly

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a discord bot and want to make it able to ban and kick the users which I mention, the issue is that even if it does say that the user I mentioned was banned successfully, it really wasn't. How can I fix this?

kick.js

```
    name: 'kick',
    description: "`Executing this command will kick the given user.`",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("**The given user has been kicked.**");
        }else{
            message.channel.send("`You have to specify who you want to kick!`");
        }
    }
}
```

ban.js

```
    name: 'ban',
    description: "`Executing this command will ban the given user.`",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.ban();
            message.channel.send("**The given user has been banned.**");
        }else{
            message.channel.send("`You have to specify who you want to banned!`");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error, warning, e.t.c. thrown?

Comment: Yep, ill post the error in the main post.

Comment: You could use `.then()` after kicking the user and put the `message.channel.send` in that. Then you could use `.catch()` to check for any particular errors. This would make it certain that the message can only be sent after the user was kicked

Answer (score -1):

You can put the messages just before the kick/ban, so that the user is available for the client:

```
const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
memberTarget.kick();
message.channel.send("**The given user has been kicked.**");
```

**becomes**

```
const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
message.channel.send("** <@"+ target.id + "> has been kicked.**");
memberTarget.kick();
```